# Can I use chrome.identity with Firebase custom authentication?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firebase, firebase-security

I'm building a Chrome extension and would like to use Firebase to persist state shared between users. Firebase authentication doesn't work within Chrome extension because there's no origin domain. The `chrome.identity` API can be used to ensure that the user is authenticated and to get the access token for OAuth requests.

A couple of considerations:

- Use `chrome.storage` to store a token and use that to authenticate with Firebase. The storage area is not encrypted, so it would be trivial to read a user's token from their disk.
- I assume the token returned by `chrome.identity.getAuthToken` is an OAuth access token and therefore transient - it wouldn't be suitable for a permanent unique identifier for a user.
- I could make a request to a Google OAuth API to exchange the access token for the user's profile (https://www.googleapis.com/userinfo/v2/me), which contains an `id` field, but this is public.

Comment: Seems to me this was asked and resolved before here on SO--maybe the mailing list. There was a creative solution to the origin issue involving making a request to a hosted web page (using Firebase hosting in that instance) that could then perform the auth check with a suitable origin. Also, [create your own tokens](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/user-security.html#section-custom) ftw.

Comment: That was suggested as the solution to using Firebase OAuth authentication (e.g. Google/Facebook/Twitter) within a Chrome extension. Chrome users authenticate with their Google ID and `chrome.identity` provides access to that authentication info. However, Firebase security rules depend on the user being authenticated with their auth service.

Comment: Not sure what you're referring to. If you create your own tokens, or authenticated with a hosted web page, in both cases you would then use that token to auth and apply to security rules.

Comment: So, turns out you can get a unique ID for the user logged in to Chrome using the `chrome.identity.getProfileUserInfo` method.

Answer (score 2):

I came across this question on my quest to solve a similar problem. I am sure the question is outdated but maybe my solution helps someone else stumbling over this question.

It is indeed possible to use `chrome.identity` for Firebase authentication... But the way is not through the custom authentication method. There is another method which accepts the OAuth2 token from `chrome.identity.getAuthToken`.

Here is everything I did following this [tutorial](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/apps/app_identity/):
(It also mentions a solution for **non-Google auth providers** that I didn't try)

#### Identity Permission

First you need permission to use the chrome identity API. You get it by adding this to your `manifest.json`:

```js
{
  ...
  "permissions": [
    "identity"
  ],
  ...
}
```

#### Consistent Application ID

You need your application ID consistent during development to use the OAuth process. To accomplish that, you need to copy the key in an installed version of your `manifest.json`.

To get a suitable `key` value, first install your extension from a `.crx` file (you may need to upload your extension or package it manually). Then, in your user data directory (on macOS it is `~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome`), look in the file Default/Extensions/EXTENSION_ID/EXTENSION_VERSION/manifest.json. You will see the key value filled in there.

```js
{
  ...
  "key": "MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAgFbIrnF3oWbqomZh8CHzkTE9MxD/4tVmCTJ3JYSzYhtVnX7tVAbXZRRPuYLavIFaS15tojlRNRhfOdvyTXew+RaSJjOIzdo30byBU3C4mJAtRtSjb+U9fAsJxStVpXvdQrYNNFCCx/85T6oJX3qDsYexFCs/9doGqzhCc5RvN+W4jbQlfz7n+TiT8TtPBKrQWGLYjbEdNpPnvnorJBMys/yob82cglpqbWI36sTSGwQxjgQbp3b4mnQ2R0gzOcY41cMOw8JqSl6aXdYfHBTLxCy+gz9RCQYNUhDewxE1DeoEgAh21956oKJ8Sn7FacyMyNcnWvNhlMzPtr/0RUK7nQIDAQAB",
  ...
}
```

Copy this line to your source `manifest.json`.

#### Register your Extension with Google Cloud APIs

You need to register your app in the **Google APIs Console** to get the client ID:

1. Search for the API you what to use and make sure it is activated in your project. In my case **Cloud Firestore API**.
2. Go to the **API Access** navigation menu item and click on the **Create an OAuth 2.0 client ID**... blue button.
3. Select **Chrome Application** and enter your application ID (same ID displayed in the extensions management page).
4. Put this **client ID** in your `manifest.json`. You only need the `userinfo.email` **scope**.

```js
{
  ...
  "oauth2": {
    "client_id": "171239695530-3mbapmkhai2m0qjb2jgjp097c7jmmhc3.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "scopes": [
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"
    ]
  }
  ...
}
```

#### Get and Use the Google Auth Token

```js
chrome.identity.getAuthToken({ 'interactive': true }, function(token) {
    // console.log("token: " + token);
    let credential = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(null, token);
    firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential)
        .then((result) => {
            // console.log("Login successful!");
            DoWhatYouWantWithTheUserObject(result.user);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
        });
});
```

*Have fun with your Firebase Service...*