# Chrome Extension Firestore Database Manifest Version 3

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am trying to connect my firestore database to my chrome extension and can find no working solutions for manifest version 3. If anyone has a solution that works, it would be greatly appreciated?
Thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://9to5google.com/2021/09/23/chrome-manifest-v2-extensions/), ManifestV3 is still half-broken so there's no solution. In their doc they say that you can use npm install firebase and follow their doc in order to connect it but this is still broken.

You can check with this [Stackoverflow Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69160743/connect-a-manifest-version-3-chrome-extension-to-a-firestore-database), where it gives an explanatory workaround for connecting the firestore database to chrome extension for manifest version 3.

Comment: Thanks so much, the link in that post to the external firebase files doesn't seem to be working however. Do you know another way to find these files?

Comment: Seems like the updates on the Chrome extension feature is not allowing to communicate with the Firestore service through the Chrome extension using manifest V3. The new update is not using the "page" background option. The service is available for RTDB, but not for Firestore. The Firestore service is still working using Manifest V2. Meanwhile you can use Firebase. This [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UjH2INUPmF4) may help you. Regarding the external firebase files link, actually it's a pattern of URL, not the link.

Comment: So is there currently no way to use firestore with manifest V3? But there is with V2, the problem is V2 becomes obsolete in 2023 i’m pretty sure, so it wouldn’t be a great idea to use it. I already have an app linked to firestore so moving to RTDB is unfavorable. I’m just checking to make sure there is no way at all that I can use firestore with V3 or is there a workaround with your first post, and if so would you be able to guide me towards the location if said files? Thanks so much and sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: As per some internal tools I can say, Chrome extension feature is not allowed to communicate with the Firestore service through the Chrome extension using manifest V3. Meanwhile you can refer to these [link](https://dev.to/swimmingkiim/chrome-extension-with-firebase-manifest-v3-27gc) and [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o_tM2ORppm8).